# Extract paragraph which contains my xml tag by python regex

Tags: python, regex, xml-parsing

I'd like to extract a paragraph which contains tag. I mean I've a text with multiple paragraphs, with in any paragraph there's tag XML for sentimental analysis. I'd like to extract every paragraph to put it in column, every tag with in that paragraph in column and the intensity of the word.
Example:

Start paragraph ...................... profound injustice ..............end paragraph

Start paragraph ...................... profound injustice ..............end paragraph

...

```
_______________________________________________
|Paragraph      | Word sentiment   | Intensity |
+_______________+__________________+___________+
|  Paragraph 1  | Dissatisfaction  |     6     |
|  Paragraph 1  | satisfaction     |     8     |
|     ....      |      ....        |     ..    |
|               |                  |           |
________________________________________________
```

To extract Wort sentiment and intensity I've written this and it works fine.

```
csv = df['text'].str.extractall(r'^<(?P<Sentiments>\w+)\s*[int].*(?P<Intensite>\d)')
```

Output:
[image: result of regex]

**My Question is how to extract also corresponding paragraph and put it in a column (by appending it or combining it to regex above)??**

Thanks

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful. I'm not clear on where the `Sentiments` and `Itensite` data are coming from.

Comment: Thanks, how could insert text here, could I share a link?

Comment: Sample text
Vous avez inventé, mon cher, l’instinctologie, et vous aurez une chaire d’Instinct Comparés. Vous allez être un grand savant, et moi je vais l’annoncer au monde, à l’Europe, à Paris, au ministre, à son secrétaire, aux commis, aux surnuméraires ! Mahomet a été <Satisfaction int=7>bien grand</Satisfaction> quand il a vu quelqu’un pour soutenir à tort et à travers qu’il était prophète.
—  Le baron Cerceau, par exemple, a passé sa vie à parquer les Animaux dans des <Disagreement int=6>divisions absolues</Disagreement>, et il y tient, c’est sa gloire à lui.

Comment: It seems its doesn’t appear as multiple paragraphs but it’s.

Comment: If your data is stored in XML format, you should use an XML parser instead of regex.

Comment: I say xml, just to indicate balise are in the text. For exemple this kind of text could I apply regex to get the output I need?